# value_counts for a specific string value returns key error if all rows empty

Tags: python, pandas

When getting `value_counts` for a specific string value from a pandas dataframe column, where all rows happen to be empty on occasion, it raises an exception:

> KeyError: 'Tom'.

I want 0 count returned.

To reproduce error:

```
data = {'Name': ['', '', '', ''],
        'Age': [29, 21, 19, 18]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Name'].value_counts()['Tom']
```

Comment: `value_counts()` returns `Series`. `df['Name'].value_counts().get('Tom', 0)` will return zero.

Comment: Dmity I think this is right, although I could leave out the Series and just write df['Name'].value_counts().get('Tom', 0) .  If you could post your comment as a proper answer I can then mark it.

Comment: I suggest that mozway's answer is good enough, extending that comment. Thanks anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like dictionaries, Series have a [`get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.get.html) method to handle non-existent keys, with a parameter to set up a default value:

```
df['Name'].value_counts().get('Tom', 0)
```

Output: `0`

If you want to access multiple values, you can also use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
df['Name'].value_counts().reindex(['Tom', 'Jerry'], fill_value=0)
```

Example output (assuming 1 Tom in the input):

```
Name
Tom      1
Jerry    0
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use try-except clauses:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['', '', '', ''],
        'Age': [29, 21, 19, 18]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

try:
    count = df['Name'].value_counts()['Tom']
except KeyError:
    count = 0

print(count)
```